# X and Y are both $N\times N$ matrices. How many of the $N^2$ equations in $XY=YX$ regarding the elements of X and Y are independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried the case of $N=2$:

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ c&d\end{pmatrix},Y=\begin{pmatrix}e&f \\ g&h\end{pmatrix}$. $XY=YX$ means that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 a e+b g & a f+b h \\
 c e+d g & c f+d h \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 a e+c f & b e+d f \\
 a g+c h & b g+d h \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
which is $N^2=4$ equations about $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$, But only $3$ of them are independent.

$tr(XY-YX)=0$, so at most $N^2-1$ equations are independent. Is $N^2-1$ the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "generic" $B$ is diagonalizable with all eigenvalues distinct, and then the only $A$ that commutes with $B$ are those that are diagonalized by the same matrix that diagonalizes $B$.  There are thus $N$ degrees of freedom for $A$ that commutes with $B$.  Since $A$ has $N^2$ entries, that means there must be $N^2 - N$ independent equations.

Comment: $N^2-N$ is not the correct answer.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Why not?

Comment: If $N^2-N$ were correct, then in particular, only $2$ of the equations (rather than $3$) would be independent in the $N=2$ case. But the OP said $3$, so $N^2-N$ cannot be correct. Also, not all square matrices are diagonalizable, so considering just the commutators of diagonalizable matrices would be too restrictive.

Comment: Actually, I believe that there are only two (algebraically) independent equations in the $N=2$ case.  The first two amount to $bg=cf$ and $af+bh = be+df$.  Multiplying the latter by $g$ gives $afg+bgh = beg+dfg \implies afg+cfh = cfe + dfg$, which is just $f$ times the third equation.  The fourth is identical to the first.

Comment: Yes, the four equations can individually be rewritten as $\frac{b}f=\frac{c}g$, $\frac{c}g=\frac{b}f$, $\frac{c}g=\frac{a-d}{e-h}$, $\frac{b}f=\frac{a-d}{e-h}$, which fairly obviously are only two independent equations.

Comment: That is, **if** you are not dividing by zero. Strictly speaking, one needs $f$ to be nonzero for the first and second equations to imply the third as pointed out by Erick Wong. If instead, $b \ne 0$, then a similar argument would show that one could multiply the second equation by $c$, make the substitution given by the first equation, and then divide by $b$ to get the third equation. If both $b$ and $f$ are zero, then the first two equations cannot be shown to imply the third. Similar considerations would apply for the first and third implying the second if either $c$ or $g$ is nonzero.

Comment: The crux here seems to be whether "independent" means linearly independent or algebraically independent.  Linearity is a plausible choice in this matrix setting, but since the expressions are themselves multilinear of degree 2, it is not the only choice.  @cxy_MO, can you clarify your intent?

Answer (score -1):

The answer of $N^2-1$ follows from the fact the commutators are exactly the matrices with trace $0$.

Indeed, the set of $N \times N$-matrices with trace $0$ is the kernel of the trace map from $k^{N^2}$ to $k$ (where $k$ is the base field, usually $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), which is easily seen to be surjective, so it has dimension $N^2-1$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

So, yes, there are exactly $N^2-1$ independent equations. All of the entries in matrices of the form $XY-YX$ except e.g., the bottom right corner, could be defined independently, and then the missing diagonal entry would be forced to be the opposite (additive inverse) of the sum of the other diagonal entries.

Comment: While $\{X|tr(X)=0\}$ has dimension $N^2-1$, I don't see how that implies $\{X|XY-YX=0\}$ also has the same dimension. You seem to be looking at the set of commutators $\{XY-YX\}$ for a given $Y$ and saying its dimension is $N^2-1$, but how does that relate?